# Symfony dynamical forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Hello I'm trying to make dynamical form and I have some problems.. I have been trying to follow http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html and some related tutorials but without result.

Currently I'm getting following error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   UserBundle\Form\Type\CompanyRegistrationFormType::UserBundle\Form\Type{closure}()
>   must be an instance of UserBundle\Entity\Sector, instance of
>   UserBundle\Entity\Company given, called in
>   UserBundle/Form/Type/CompanyRegistrationFormType.php on line 82 and defined

I have 3 entity table:

Company.php

```
  /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sector", mappedBy="company")
  */
  protected $sector;
```

Sector.php

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
*/
protected $name;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="sector")
*/
protected $company;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MainCategory", mappedBy="sector")
 */
 protected $mainCategory;
```

MainCategory.php

```
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $name;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sector", inversedBy="mainCategory")
    */
    protected $sector;
```

FormType.php

```
$builder->add('sector', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'UserBundle:Company'));
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Sector $sector = null) {
    $mainCategories = null === $sector ? array() : $sector->getAvailableMainCategories();

    $form->add('mainCategory', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'UserBundle:Sector',
        'choices' => $mainCategories));
};

$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

        $data = $event->getData();

        $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data);
    });

$builder->get('sector')->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

        $sector = $event->getForm()->getData();

        $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $sector);
    });
```

and twig:

```
  {{ form_row(form.sector) }} {# <select id="company_sector" #}
  {{ form_row(form.mainCategory) }} {# select id="company_mainCategory" #}

      <script>

       var $sector = $('#company_sector');
       $sport.change(function(){

       var $form = $(this).closest('form');

        var data = {};
        data[$sector.attr('name')] = $sector.val();

        $.ajax({
            url : $form.attr('action'),
            type : $form.attr('method'),
            data : data,
            success: function(html) {
        $('#company_mainCategory').replaceWith(
        $(html).find('#company_mainCategory'));
                    }
                });
            });
      </script>
```

**Line 82**

```
$formModifier($event->getForm(), $data);
```

if I change it to

```
 $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getSector());
```

I get following error:

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   UserBundle\Entity\Company::$mainCategory

can someone help me out? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

```
$builder->add('sector', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'UserBundle:Company'));
```

You have to pass in class parameter classname associated with entity Sector (i suppose `UserBundle:Sector`)

[Documentation for symfony2 entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#class)